# How to convert Roman numerals with dashes?

Tags: notation, math-history

What does the dash mean over the symbols here?
How to convert these Roman numerals to numbers?

[image: Image showing roman numerals as replicated in the text form below.]

Textual equivalent of the image:

$$\overline{\text{M}}\,\overline{\text{L}}\,\overline{\text{V}}\text{MCCLXXIX} \text{ et } \overline{\text{C}}\,\overline{\text{M}}\,\overline{\text{V}}\text{CCCLXXXII}$$

Comment: ["Another system is the vinculum, where a conventional Roman numeral is multiplied by 1,000 by adding an overline"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Large_numbers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bar means multiplying by $1000$, so the numbers in the picture are $1056279$ and $905382$.

Answer (score 7):

Typically the dash over the Roman numeral multiplies that part by 1000.